# Exchange Web Services, ASP.NET with Windows Auth, IIS 8.5 and Impersonation

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, impersonation, iis-8, ews-managed-api

I am being driven slowly and inexorably mad by the setup of IIS to allow access to Exchange Web Services from ASP.NET website that uses Windows Authentication. I have found literally dozens of articles on how to set this up, each of which seems to say something different, or else describes a process to me that fails when I duplicate it, presumably by there being some assumed knowledge on my part.

- Application uses windows authentication to identify the user.
- Application sends emails using EWS such that the email ends up in the users "sent items"
- Exchange is hosted on a separate server than the web server, so I am assuming the "double-hop" I have read about issue is occurring. I am not a sysadmin, so I do not really understand this.

Is there some clear way for me to setup this up to work, and then potentially troubleshoot the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, from your description it certainly looks like a double-hop problem. It's non-trivial to fix, basically you need to setup delegation between the web server and the exchange server to  for the web server to be able to use the kerberos ticket issued when the user logs in to the web server.

I have yet to deploy a single solution that actually does that. We have always ended up either using a service account (with appropriate access rights to exchange, mailboxes etc.) or place the web application on the exchange server. Neither option is particularly elegant, but in most cases operations teams have been unwilling to set up delegation or known how to do it properly.